# Get an array from a text file to be a list in python

Tags: python

I have a text file which contains an array like this example:

```
myarray=['banana', 'carrot', 'apple']
```

I have to read all the lines in that file and get the content of myarray, but I don't know how to tell python that that content is a list.

```
with open(myFilePath) as myFile:
    for line in myFile:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if 'myarray' in line:
            line_splitted = line.split('myarray=')
            if len(line_splitted) > 1:
                myArrayContent = line_splitted[1]
```

Python, as it is logical, read myArrayContent as string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use module AST:

```
import ast
myarray = ast.literal_eval(line.split("=")[1])
#['banana', 'carrot', 'apple']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply numpy :

```
import numpy as np
with open('file','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(np.array(line.split('=')[1]))
```

output:

```
['banana', 'carrot', 'apple']
```

Comment: What would be the benefit over the @Dyz answer of importing ast? Is there any performance improvements or just 2 ways of doing it?

Comment: @codiaf read this https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html